# knockout error - Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I get the following error when running my knockout code:
     Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
     Message: ReferenceError: measures is not defined;
     Bindings value: template: { name: 'measureDispTmpl', foreach: measures, as: 'food' }

You can see the jsfiddle code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nickbuus/eUufc/

When I click the + icon I want the addMeasure method to be called - so that I can add a new measure to the current foodItem and save it. But when I try to call the addMeasure then the method:

```
 self.addMeasure = function (myItem)
```

is never called and I get the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle. In your code you add a mesureItem in the foodList of the viewModel.
That's why the food template doesn't work (because it tries to show an measure and a measure doesn't an measures property).

```
self.addMeasure = function (myItem) {
    var foodIte = self.selectedItem();
    var newItem = new MeasureItem();
    // mine 
    myItem.measures.push(newItem);
    self.selectedItem(newItem);
   // your :
   //self.list.push(newItem);
};
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eUufc/4/)

**In response to your question :**

Just add this at end of the addMeasure function:

```
self.selectedItem(newItem);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Would you also know how I can make the new row go right into the edittemplate display after being created -> so that it will pick the 'measureEditTmpl' instead of the 'measureDispTmpl' as default.

Comment: I modified my post accordingly to your question.

Comment: Thank you Damien - any chance you could fix my code so that if I press the cancel button on a newly created measure it will remove that newly created measure?

Comment: I figured it out by adding one more observable: 

     self.selectedFoodItem = ko.observable();

And then I added this to the cancel method:
     self.cancel = function () {
     var selectedFood = self.selectedFoodItem();
     selectedFood.measures.pop();
        self.selectedItem(null);
     };
And this to addMeasure:
     self.addMeasure = function (myItem) {
     self.selectedFoodItem(myItem);

But this fix introduced a new problem: if I click cancel on existing rows it will also delete these - can you please help me fix this.

Comment: For instance is there a way to only delete the current editable measure item if the input text is empty when pressing cancel?