# Knockout cancel editable row functionality depending on new or existing item

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have this code where I have made a child edit functionality for each item. When I press the "+" icon it creates a new child row that I can then edit and save - When I click the "cancel" icon I want the newly created child row to be removed but when I click "cancel" on one of the existing rows that have existing data I don't want the row to be removed. How can this be solved ? Should I check if the input text field is empty to decide if it should be removed again - or is there another way to solve it?

Comment: Refered question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978731/knockout-error-uncaught-error-unable-to-parse-bindings/16979561#16979561

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eUufc/8/) in which I added a isNew property on MeasureItem. So with this property you can distinguish if the MeasureItem is a new one ot not. I also move the cancel function to the FoodItem class.

JS:

```
var MeasureItem = function (id, name) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.isNew = false;
};
function FoodItem(id, name, mItems) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.measures = ko.observableArray(mItems);
    self.cancel = function (item) {
        vm.selectedItem(null);
        if(this.isNew)
           self.measures.remove(item);
    };
}
```

Edit template :

```
<script id="measureEditTmpl" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <input data-bind="value: food.name"/>
        <a class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: $root.save" href="#" title="save"><i class="icon-ok"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $parent.cancel" href="#" title="cancel"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
    </li>
</script>
```

[**See Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eUufc/8/)

Comment: It worked perfectly - thanks for your help. Perhaps you can solve this one also:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999035/ability-to-update-list-without-reloading-it-when-editing-a-row-using-knockoutjs